# how i can give role to member who send modal?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a modal in my server and I want to add a role to the guild member who submits the modal, how can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

    let name = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('nameInput');
    let age = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('ageInput');
    let time = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('timeInput');
    let online = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('onlineInput');
    let bio = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('bioInput');

    const buttoninvyes = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('buttoninvyes')
        .setLabel('Принять')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success);

    const buttoninvno = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('buttoninvno')
        .setLabel('отклонить')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);

    const buttoninvyesRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(buttoninvyes);
    const buttoninvnoRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(buttoninvno);

    let embedinvreq = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Новая завявка в Famq')
        .setDescription(`Данные игрока: \n Игровое имя - ***${name}*** \n Discord - ***${interaction.user}*** \n возраст - ***${age}*** \n часовой пояс - ***${time}*** \n время игры - ***${online}*** \n биография - ***${bio}***`)
        .setColor('LuminousVividPink')
        .setTimestamp();

    const channelinv = "1173243142032609340";
    client.channels.cache.get(channelinv).send({embeds: [embedinvreq], components: [buttoninvyesRow, buttoninvnoRow]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/GuildMember:Class) who triggered the interaction with [`interaction.member`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/ModalSubmitInteraction:Class#member) and then add the role to them as normal.

```js
const interactingMember = interaction.member;
const guildRole = interaction.guild.roles.find(role => role.id === "YOUR_ROLE_ID");

// Add the role to the user who submit the modal.
interactingMember.roles.add(guildRole);
```

Comment: I need it to assign a role to the user who submitted the form by clicking a button

Comment: meybe to connect interaction of modalSubmit and give role for member interaction of modal

Comment: Yes, this code answer is the solution to what you are asking. `interaction` is the interaction object when the user clicks submit; place this code within your `interactionCreate` event handler.